# How to pass host variables to Docker in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Application needs to have access to the environment variables set in the config console in Elastic Beanstalk.
How can i pass those to my docker container?

Answer (score 0):

FYI i meant passing it from docker container to nginx. Fixed with using OpenResty!